# 22.04 mouse drag-and-drop select text not working

Tags: mouse, drag-and-drop

In 20.04 mouse drag selected texts to another application. For instance mark a text of Chromium translation and drag it with the held left bottom and releace/drop it to a gedit text file.
In 22.04 when I release the left bottom the dragged text just disappear and do not been added to the destination.

(I can stil mark and copy it to the destination.)